# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Kernel getting Frequent reboot on VMware

Tags: kernel, vmware, reboot

Experiencing recurrent sudden reboots on multiple Ubuntu 22.04 LTS VMs hosted on VMware, irrespective of the running applications. Using Linux Kernel versions "**5.15.0-78-generic x86_64**" or "**5.15.0-57-generic x86_64**", and VMware version 14. Plz suggest for solutions if any.

Comment: VMWare 14 has long been unsupported (from 2019). Can you upgrade to the latest release?

Comment: it is running fine for other VMs hosted on the same VMware setup.

Comment: Look into what you see in `/var/log/*` files, `zcat file.gz | less` will display the *.gz ones.